# WSO2 API Manager 1.8 - Trying out XACML - Error creating the policy

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to see how XACML can be used with the API Manager for controlling access to some of the resources. I have followed the blog post here,

http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/02/use-of-wso2-api-manager-to-validate-fine-grained-policy-decisions-using-xacml/

I have also tried following one more post from the following link,
http://niranjankaru.blogspot.fr/2014/11/user-role-based-access-to-api-using.html

Also, I have gone through most of the Stackoverflow question regarding this topic. The following are my questions,

1. Are the versions of the "XACML (4.2.2)" and "XACML Mediation (4.2.2)" compatible with the API Manager 1.8?
2. I'm getting an error when I try to create a policy. I'm using the simple policy editor in the "Add New Policy" page and following the same instructions as given in the first blog link.

The error shown in the UI is,

```
"Error while adding entitlement policy. Invalid Entitlement Policy. Policy is not valid according to XACML schema"
```

and the log has the following error,

```
ERROR - EntitlementUtil XACML policy is not valid according to the schema :cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'Description'. One of '{"urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17":Description, "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17":PolicyIssuer, "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17":PolicyDefaults, "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17":Target}' is expected.
```

As I am not editing policy by hand and using the Simple Policy Editor and entering all the fields required, I did not expect this error. Any idea if this can be a real error or due to some version mismatch?

Comment: Can you share your policy? I will be able to validate it with the Axiomatics Policy Server. There are have been similar bug reports on the WSO2 IS before so I am not surprised.

Comment: I have not written this policy. I'm using a UI within WSO2 management console to create this policy. Also, I'm new to XACML, so I won't be able to provide a XML version of the policy I'm trying to create using the UI

Comment: The creation of the policy itself is failing, so I'm not finding any reference to the policy it is internally creating and validating

Comment: Can you use a different authoring tool e.g. the ALFA Plugin for Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have installed the XACML features in the APIM. Issues must be due to version mismatch in the OSGI bundle that contains in APIM 1.8.0 and the XACML feature that you have installed.  I have seen there are lot issues after installing the XACML feature in APIM.  Because APIM 1.8.0 and IS 5.0.0 have not been released in same time. Therefore there are some version mismatch issues.  You download IS 5.0.0 and try to create policies and see whether there are issues are generating.

However,  if you going for proper deployment,  I think what is in above article is not correct.  Normally XACML engine must be externalized and run as separate entity. It can not be within the API Gateway. Therefore it is better to use different server for running a XACML engine. you can find more details from [here](http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/10/24/authorization-for-apis-with-xacml-and-oauth-2-0/).  Also in above article, it just have install XACML feature in APIM.. But you can call the WSO2IS using `entitlement mediator`.  you just want to provide the proper url for it in the mediator configuration.  It is suggest to use WSO2IS and try out above article. You can find more details about creating XACML policies from [here](http://xacmlinfo.org/category/xacml-editor/) using WSO2IS XACML editor.

Comment: HI Asela, In the bolg its using Oath Authorization server, But what if we just want to use API manager as PEP and Wso2 Identity server as PDP. ? And For SSO and other thing we can use Functionality of IS. IS it possible?How to configure API Manager to act as PEP?

Comment: Yes..  that is also possible. then you can use entitlement mediator in the APIM...  but i guess preferred method is using the WSO2IS as Key manager.  Please refer this doc..... https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Configuring+WSO2+Identity+Server+as+the+Key+Manager   then WSO2IS would be the authorization server/SAML2 IDP/PDP  also as token are validated in the authorization server (WSO2IS)  WSO2IS would be the PEP also....  you can use scope handler that is mentioned in the blog to  talk to the PDP for validating the token... therefore  scope handler would be the actual PEP