# Error in creating XACML policy with policy editor on WSO2 Identity Server management console- wso2is-km-5.3.0

Tags: authorization, xacml, abac, alfa, wso2-identity-server

I am using the pre-packaged IS WSO2IS-km-5.3.0 to integrate IS as a key manager with WSO2 AM 2.1.0. When I tried to create a policy with the policy editor on WSO2 Identity Server management console, the policy creation failed with the following message:

***Error while adding entitlement policy. Invalid Entitlement Policy. Policy is not valid according to XACML schema***

This happens whether I try to create a policy using any of the editor options - basic policy editor, Simple policyset editor, policyset editor.

The Policy is successfully added when we set the value as

***PDP.SchemaValidation.Enable = false*** in *entitlement.properties* file at 
*IS_HOME/repository/conf/identity* location.

Please let me know which configuration is required to create policy.
I have found the below link regarding this but not able to solve my issue:

[WSO2 API Manager 1.8 - Trying out XACML - Error creating the policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28601837/wso2-api-manager-1-8-trying-out-xacml-error-creating-the-policy)

xacml version:5.7.5 for IS and APIM and
XACML Mediation 4.6.10 on  APIM

Comment: Just check that your XACML Policy(Set) is valid against [XACML schema](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/xacml-core-v3-schema-wd-17.xsd). If you need help with that, just show us your Policy or PolicySet in XACML.

Comment: I am creating the Policy using editor through the IS management console:Home  > Entitlement  > PAP  > Policy Administration ->Add New Entitlement Policy   .. creating the Simple Policy and getting the above message

Comment: Can you switch to the source view in that Policy Editor? Like on the [picture](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Creating+a+XACML+Policy?preview=/60494109/60495017/image2013-9-13%2018%3A13%3A54.png) in section "Write policy in XML" of WSO2 IS documentation? There should be a way to get the XACML form somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard policy editor, which is the recommended editor for writing XACML policies.

If that didn't work, you can try editing an XACML policy template which is available according to your requirement.

You should keep the PDP.SchemaValidation.Enable=true, in entitlement.properties file which is the default value.

Please refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Creating+a+XACML+Policy for more information on creating XACML policies.